# Compare Integers without if statement?

Tags: scala, match

For a homework assignment, I am being asked to merge two lists of integers in non-decreasing order. We are told not to "not use the if operator."

I can merge the two lists through recursion without any difficulty (if I ignore the non-decreasing part), but how I do I compare one integer from each list without using an if statement? From what I've seen, the Scala match feature does not allow expressions, but I'm unsure how to utilize that in this case.

Not necessarily looking for explicit answers / code samples, just looking for hints towards the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the *exact wording* about the if statement restriction?

Comment: "do not use the if operator."

Comment: The comparing bit is easy (no `if` involved), it's what to do after the comparison that's harder. But consider this as a cheap very non-clever approach: `(x > b) match { ... }`

Comment: Ah, I did not know that syntax was acceptable.  Thank you very much.

Comment: If you told us _what_ you are studying, it might be easier to answer.

Comment: Next assignment; hello world without writing a single line of code.  Go!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `max` and `min` methods to allow you to cons both numbers on to the result in the proper non-decreasing order. Be sure to prove (at least to yourself) that this works in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

There's lots of way of doing this without using the `if` statement, but still resorting to comparing the numbers. That would be simply hiding an implicit `if` statement behind something else.

One alternative to `if` statements in object-oriented languages is polymorphism. Consider this:

```
sealed trait Bool
object Bool {
  def apply(b: Boolean): Bool = b match {
    case true /* Implicit if! */ => True
    case false                   => False
object True extends Bool
object False extends Bool
```

From a `Boolean` you can construct a `Bool` (using an implicit `if`, granted). You can then add a method to `Bool`, implementing it differently for each `object`. This is how `Option` works, by the way. `None` has one implementation, and `Some` has another.

There's one way to avoid *comparing* the numbers, however. If you don't compare, you don't use `if` either -- not even implicitly. Fun fact: a computer magazine back in the 80s had a contest for sorting algorithms, the winner of which would be the one comparing the fewest time. The winning algorithm sorted entirely without comparing, and then did a dummy compare just to stay within the rules of the contest.

The tip here is that you have to know what the range of the numbers is, and that range cannot be too big, or, otherwise, you'll have to do multiple passes to finish the ordering. Also, lists are inefficient to perform the operations.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The technique Daniel hints at at the end is the one that would get my vote as genuinely avoiding conditionals as opposed to encoding them out of sight somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.  But, hilariously, it works.  Let's assume you're comparing x and y.

```
val okay = Array(0,1)
try {
  b(math.signum(x.toLong - y.toLong).toInt)
  // Handle x >= y case here
}
catch { case _ =>
  // Handle x < y case here
}
```

You could also

```
val handler = Array(
  () => {
    // Handle x < y
  },
  () => {
    // Handle x == y
  },
  () => {
    // Handle x > y
  }
)
handler(math.signum(x.toLong-y.toLong).toInt+1)()
```

which is slightly less silly (but still rather silly).